# Serial loop stopped after a while, I don't know why

Tags: serial

I am very new to Arduino. I wrote a program in order to read some registers in a I2C device. I receive HEX datas.

So the Arduino LEONARDO is connected to the external board using the 2-wires-bus.
Then informations are sent to my computer by using Serial.println.

My problem is my Arduino stops working after a while, maybe 25 or 30 loops. Sometimes I loose communication and I have to reboot the Arduino.

I guess it's an overflow issue or I'm loosing connection randomly :

```
int dt = 500;
int dt2 = 1000; // used for delay duration
#include "Wire.h"
#include <Process.h>
#define pot_address 0x25 // each I2C object has a unique bus address, the MCP40

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  Wire.beginTransmission(pot_address);
  Wire.write(0); //
   Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(pot_address,8);
  byte b = Wire.read();


  Wire.beginTransmission(pot_address);
  Wire.write(1); //
   Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(pot_address,8);
 byte c = Wire.read();


   Wire.beginTransmission(pot_address);
  Wire.write(2); //
   Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(pot_address,8);
 byte d = Wire.read();


  Wire.beginTransmission(pot_address);
  Wire.write(3); //
   Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(pot_address,8);
 byte e = Wire.read();

  Wire.beginTransmission(pot_address);
  Wire.write(4); //
   Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(pot_address,8);
 byte f = Wire.read();

  Serial.print("b");
  Serial.println(b, HEX);
  Serial.println("-");
  Serial.print("c");
  Serial.println(c, HEX);
  Serial.println("-");
  Serial.print("d");
  Serial.println(d, HEX);
  Serial.println("-");
  Serial.print("e");
  Serial.println(e, HEX);
  Serial.println("-");
  Serial.print("f");
  Serial.println(f, HEX);
  Serial.println("-");

 delay(dt2);


}
```

Comment: On each transaction, you request 8 bytes from the MCP40 (second argument of `Wire.requestFrom()`), yet you read only one (one single call to `Wire.read()`).

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
while(!Serial) ;
```

I'll make sure the Leonardo is in sync with the Serial communication.

It is the case because the Leonardo is USB native thus the Serial communication works differently.